# Bulk updates in CouchDB-Ektorp - shouldn't update conflicts be returned?

Tags: couchdb, ektorp

I have been using the Ektorp (1.3.0) framework to connect to my CouchDB databases.
There is a problem when there's update conflicts though.
I am using the method  `executeAllOrNothing` for bulk updates. As documented, this method (as well as the HTTP API equivalent  `_bulk_docs?all_or_nothing":true` does not make any checks for conflicts. From the [HTTP API docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API#Transactional_Semantics_with_Bulk_Updates):

> However if the document with id 0 had a conflict, both versions will
>   be present in the database, with an arbitrary choice made as to which
>   appears in views. You can check for this status using a GET with
>   ?conflicts=true

Also:

> Applications that rely on this functionality should be able to
>   tolerate some documents missing or being in a conflicted state until
>   conflict resolution can occur.

However, the Ektorp's javadocs for the method say that:

> The list (returned) will only contain entries for documents that has any kind of error code returned from CouchDB. i.e. the list will be empty if everything was completed successfully.

I have found that this is not the case. When conflicts occur, Ektorp still returns an empty list. The only way I found to get the list of failed operations was by using `executeBulk` rather than `executeAllOrNothing`, but this is not satisfactory as I need this to be a transaction.

Is there any way I can get to know whether the call to `executeAllOrNothing` succeeded, and if it didn't, what documents had conflict problems (without recurring to using `GET with conflicts=true` for each doc as I can potentially attempt to save thousands of documents at once, so this would be impractical)?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior described in the ektorp doc that you referred to is not CouchDB behavior.  With `all_or_nothing:true` CouchDB just returns the success objects (`ok`, `id` and new `rev`) in an array with no indication at all that they're conflicted.

So, that behavior (the removal of successful objects from that array) is something which ektorp must (be meant to) do.  So this sounds like a bug in ektorp.  You should see [their github project](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp) for how to report a bug.

Comment: I agree, it's a bug in Ektorp, although the CouchDB behaviour is quite odd in explicitly having views choose the winning revision arbitrarily when a conflict occurs. But I understand this is a limitation of the replication model.

Comment: You see replication, I see predictable automatic conflict resolution :)